# How to split product on Shopify from one variant into two variants

Tags: shopify

I'm a newbie to Shopify. I currently have a product that has both size and frame options as the same variant. I am trying to switch these so that the size and frame options are separate variants but want to maintain the SKU numbers and integrity of DSers tracking through Shopify.

Please provide me suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: hopefully, this will help you https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/dropshipping/oberlo/products-and-pricing/splitting-variants#:~:text=From%20your%20import%20list%2C%20find,Click%20Split%20to%20Products.